# COMODO firewall - Block Windows "run on startup" setup

Tags: windows-7, startup, firewall

I want COMODO Firewall to alert me everytime, when some application try to setup itself to run on Windows startup.

Is it possible with COMODO Fiewall? For example ZoneAlarm can do this.

Thanks.